# How to generate unique ID in clustering

Tags: java

Is there any clustering API that helps in generating the unique ID across many servers?

Comment: You've missed the point of this site. Questions and answers here are public precisely to reduce the need to ask the same thing over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

Reserve some IDs

```
Server 1:   1000000.. 2999999
Server 2:   2000000.. 3999999
...
Server 3:   3000000.. 3999999
```

You may add some inteligence so that the reservation is dinamic but there is no need.

Answer (score 2):

Use [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID).
Even though a collision is possible in practice, the odds are soooo astronomically low that everybody uses it, including critical industrial applications.
[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates) is a discussion about the collision probability.

Comment: From that wiki document: "However, these probabilities only hold when the UUIDs are generated using sufficient entropy. Otherwise the probability of duplicates may be significantly higher, since the statistical dispersion may be lower".  

For that reason, some people like to partition the space, for example by prepending a server instance identifier (like hostname-pid).

Answer (score 2):

Hazelcast is super simple, open source clustering solution for java. 
Here is the quote from documentation.

Hazelcast IdGenerator creates cluster-wide unique IDs. Generated IDs are long type primitive values between 0 and Long.MAX_VALUE . Id generation occurs almost at the speed of AtomicLong.incrementAndGet() . Generated IDs are unique during the life cycle of the cluster. If the entire cluster is restarted, IDs start from 0 again.

import com.hazelcast.core.IdGenerator;

import com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast;

IdGenerator idGenerator = Hazelcast.getIdGenerator("customer-ids");

long id = idGenerator.newId();

http://www.hazelcast.com/documentation.jsp#IdGenerator

Answer (score 0):

I'm using hazelcast, a very good clustering framework, providing the unique id and much more.

Comment: Is there any specific API that is provided specially for generating unique ID on JBOS cluster?